# How to get statistics in Z3 3.2?

Tags: statistics, z3, ini

With Z3 2.x I used the SMTLib2 command

```
(get-info statistics)
```

to get statistics of a Z3 run. Using Z3 3.2 I get

```
(error "line _ column _: invalid command argument, keyword expected")
```

for the above, and to

```
(get-info :statistics)
```

Z3 replies with

```
unsupported
```

What's the new way of getting statistics (other than the /st command-line option)?

---

And while we're at it: The [INI options page](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/config.html) lists

```
(set-option :STATISTICS true)
```

as a valid option, but Z3 3.2 again replies with

```
unsupported
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(get-info :all-statistics)
```

should do the trick.

Official example: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/doc_examples

Comment: It indeed does, thanks! Is it mentioned somewhere in the docs?

Comment: I saw it when browsing through Z3's examples at http://rise4fun.com/samples (see my update).

Comment: Is there maybe even a way of getting a specific statistic, e.g. "conflicts" or "quant-instantiations"?

Comment: I don't think so. Z3 team wants to keep the core as small as possible.