# How do I find the memory consumed in modeling/checking the satisfiability in Z3py?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using z3py. I am trying to check the satisfiability for different problems  with different sizes and verify the scalability of the proposed method. However, to do that I need to know the memory consumed by the solver for each problem. Is there a way to access the memory or make the z3py print it in the STATISTICS section. Thank you so much in advance.

**Update-27/5/2015:**

I tried with the paython memory profiler but it seems that the generated memory is very large. I am not sure but the reported memory is similar to the memory consumed by the python application and not only Z3(constructing the z3 model and checking the sat and then generating model). Moreover, I used formal modeling checking tools for many years now. I am expecting Z3 to be more efficient and have better scalability, however, I am getting much less memory than what the paython is generating. 
What I am thinking to do is to try to measure the design size or the scalability using factors other than memory.  In z3py statistics  many details are generated to describe the design size and complexity. However, I am not able to find any explanation of these parameters in the tutorial, webpage, or z3 papers. 
For example, can you help me understand the following parameters generated in the statistics for one of the basic models I have. Also is there any parameter/parameters which can replace the memory or be good indication of the Z3 mdoel size/complexity.

- :added-eqs               152
- :assert-lower            2
- :assert-upper            2
- :binary-propagations     59
- :conflicts               6
- :datatype-accessor-ax    12
- :datatype-constructor-ax 14
- :datatype-occurs-check   19
- :datatype-splits         12
- :decisions               35
- :del-clause              2
- :eq-adapter              2
- :final-checks            1
- :mk-clause               9
- :offset-eqs              2
- :propagations            61

Thank again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Z3 approximates the global maximum memory usage, but it does not have facilities for tracking the memory usage of one particular call to the API. In cases where the global memory usage decreases, this won't be enough (e.g., should it be negative?). I think that external tools like the Python [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) would do a much better job.

The updated question is a recurring one, please see these earlier answers: [Interpretation of Z3 Statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491922/interpretation-of-z3-statistics), [What is the unit of memory usage in Z3 statistics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007806/what-is-the-unit-of-memory-usage-in-z3-statistics), [Z3 statistics: what does time measure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340888/z3-statistics-what-does-time-measure), [Z3 real arithmetic and statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949633/z3-real-arithmetic-and-statistics), [Statistics in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064533/statistics-in-z3), [How to get statistics in Z3 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786081/how-to-get-statistics-in-z3-3-2).

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have updated my question according to your comment can you please check the update. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have added statistics for memory consumption into the unstable branch.
So by now you should be able to access this information from the statistics
returned by Z3.